# type 'List<Object?>' is not a subtype of type 'List<>' in type cast

Tags: java, android, flutter, dart

What I'm trying to do is to communicate between Flutter and Android. For this I'm using EventChannel and MethodChannel. Due to codec restrictions I need to wrap my Android data in HashMap before sending it to Flutter. On the Flutter side I'm trying to unwrap it for display in the simple ListView. However, I have problem with typecasting that I can't figure out

```
factory BLEService.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) => BLEService(
    map['uuid'] as String,
    (map['characteristics'] as List<BLECharacteristic>)
        .map<BLECharacteristic>((e)  =>
      BLECharacteristic.fromMap(e as Map<String, BLECharacteristic>)
    ).toList()
  );
```

For this line the following exception is thrown:
`type 'List<Object?>' is not a subtype of type 'List<BLECharacteristic>' in type cast`

Help to solve this issue would be greatly appreciated

---

Edit
Flutter BLECharacteristic.fromMap

```
factory BLECharacteristic.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) => BLECharacteristic(
    map['uuid'] as String,
  );
```

Java BLECharacteristic.toMap

```
HashMap<String, Object> toMap() {
        HashMap<String, Object> bleCharacteristicMap = new HashMap<>();
        bleCharacteristicMap.put("uuid", uuid);
        return bleCharacteristicMap;
    }
```

Comment: can you show what does map['characteristics'] returns?

Comment: {"characteristics":[{"uuid":"00002a00-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"},{"uuid":"00002a01-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"},{"uuid":"00002a02-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"},{"uuid":"00002a04-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"}],"uuid":"00001800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I figured out a bit hacky method to solve it:

```
var finalList = Map<String, dynamic>.from(jsonDecode(jsonEncode(data)))['SERVICESLIST'].map<BLEService>((e) => BLEService.fromMap(e)).toList();
```

However, to make simple I just changed the Android implementation to wrap the data using JSON with gson plugin

Answer (score 0):

In Flutter the `map['characteristics']` will return a `List<Object?>` and not a `List<BLECharacteristic>`. So the below code might work for you (not tested):

```
factory BLEService.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) => BLEService(
    map['uuid'] as String,
    (map['characteristics'] as List)
        ?.map((e)  =>
      BLECharacteristic.fromMap(e as Map<String, dynamic>)
    ).toList()
  );
```

Can you show the `fromMap` and `toMap` methods for `BLECharactertic` for better understanding of the problem.

Comment: Thanks for fast response :) I have added requested function in the original post for better visibility. In the meantime I will test your suggestion.
This solution is not going to work as the there will be same typing problems with underlying HashMap

Comment: I tried running this on DartPad and it works. Heres the [link](https://dartpad.dev/?id=a8b1a3cfd01d226256c37d0571305f43&null_safety=true)

Answer (score 0):

try this code once

```
List<BLECharacteristic> bleCharacteristicFromJson(List list) =>
List<BLECharacteristic>.from(
      list.map((x) => BLECharacteristic.fromJson(x)));

class BLECharacteristic {
  BLECharacteristic({this.uuid});

  String? uuid;

  factory BLECharacteristic.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      BLECharacteristic(
        uuid: json["uuid"],
      );
}
```

and call it like this

```
final data = bleCharacteristicFromJson(map["characteristics"]); // will return you list of BLECharacteristic
```